# Convert EPSG:3068 to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools, wgs84, epsg

So I have a GeoJSON with EPSG:3068 and I would like to convert the coordinates to WGS84(EPSG:4326). I could also convert them before I write them to GeoJSON. I could not find an algorithm for the conversion. I prefer Java, but any other scripts would be ok as well.

My code looks like this:

public static void convert() throws NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException, IOException, MismatchedDimensionException, TransformException{
    // CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3068");
    // CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

```
String SoldnerBerlinWKT = "PROJCS[\"DHDN / Soldner Berlin\","
           + "GEOGCS[\"DHDN\",DATUM[\"Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz\","
           + "SPHEROID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7004\"]],"
           + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6314\"]]," 
           + "PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],"
           + "UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],"
           + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4314\"]]," 
           + "UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],"
           + "PROJECTION[\"Cassini_Soldner\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",52.41864827777778],"
           + "PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",13.62720366666667],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",40000],"
           + "PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",10000],"
           + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3068\"],AXIS[\"y\",EAST],AXIS[\"x\",NORTH]]";
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.parseWKT(SoldnerBerlinWKT);
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"); //line 74
MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
GeometryJSON jsonReader = new GeometryJSON();
Geometry sourceGeometry = jsonReader.read("C:\\Users\\Selphi\\Desktop\\test.geojson");
Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform(sourceGeometry, transform); 
System.out.println(sourceGeometry.toString());
System.out.println(targetGeometry.toString());
```

}

and I get this error (maybe some jars missing?):

```
Nov 13, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedPostgreSQLEpsgFactory isAvailable
WARNUNG: Unavailable authority factory: European Petroleum Survey Group
org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException: Failed to connect to the EPSG database.
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:441)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:262)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:519)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:447)
    at Test.convert(Test.java:74)
    at Test.main(Test.java:53)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check the correctness of host name and port number and check whether the data base server accepts TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:87)
    at org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource.getConnection(BaseDataSource.java:70)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.DirectEpsgFactory.getConnection(DirectEpsgFactory.java:3196)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:436)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:76)
    ... 31 more

Nov 13, 2014 9:50:49 AM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory createDataSource
INFORMATION: Building new data source for org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcDataSource
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.createDataSource(ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory.java:216)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore0(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:386)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedEpsgFactory.createBackingStore(ThreadedEpsgFactory.java:434)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.getBackingStore(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:133)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.BufferedAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(BufferedAuthorityFactory.java:235)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.DeferredAuthorityFactory.isAvailable(DeferredAuthorityFactory.java:119)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAvailable(FactoryRegistry.java:667)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.isAcceptable(FactoryRegistry.java:501)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry$1.filter(FactoryRegistry.java:192)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.advance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.FilterIterator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.getServiceProviders(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.getServiceProviders(FactoryRegistry.java:197)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:180)
    at org.geotools.referencing.ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactories(ReferencingFactoryFinder.java:455)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.getBackingFactory(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:88)
    at org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory.<init>(DefaultAuthorityFactory.java:69)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.getAuthorityFactory(CRS.java:262)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:519)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode(CRS.java:447)
    at Test.convert(Test.java:74)
    at Test.main(Test.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: It may be good to know that official support for CRS is going to be removed from the GeoJSON http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-butler-geojson-04.

Comment: Ah thanks! That shouldn't be a problem, I could switch to GML easily

Comment: EPSG:3068 seems to have axis in northing-easting order but I guess that you know that already and can handle the case when converting coordinates to/from GML3 and other formats.

Comment: Which is line 74?

Comment: Updated the code. I removed the wrong Mathtransform transform line and updated the error message. Oh and line 74 is   CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
(also commented in the code)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest not writing this yourself, but instead using one of the existing coordinate transform libraries, such as [proj4j](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4j/) or the [CRS part of GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/crs.html). From GeoTools (with some JTS help):

```java
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON;

String SoldnerBerlinWKT = "PROJCS[\"DHDN / Soldner Berlin\","
   + "GEOGCS[\"DHDN\",DATUM[\"Deutsches_Hauptdreiecksnetz\","
   + "SPHEROID[\"Bessel 1841\",6377397.155,299.1528128,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7004\"]],"
   + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6314\"]]," +
   + "PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],"
   + "UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],"
   + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4314\"]]," +
   + "UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],"
   + "PROJECTION[\"Cassini_Soldner\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",52.41864827777778],"
   + "PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",13.62720366666667],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",40000],"
   + "PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",10000],"
   + "AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3068\"],AXIS[\"y\",EAST],AXIS[\"x\",NORTH]]";

CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.parseWKT(SoldnerBerlinWKT);
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
GeometryJSON jsonReader = new GeometryJSON();

Geometry sourceGeometry = jsonReader.read(inputStreamWithJSONdata);
// you could also get the sourceGeometry using  the read(Object) method,
// which takes a File, or a String containing a filename, or a Reader
// instance.

Geometry targetGeometry = JTS.transform(sourceGeometry, transform);
```

If you'd like another language, see http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/ or one of the other variants linked off the [metacrs page](http://trac.osgeo.org/metacrs/wiki/WikiStart).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your code but I don't know what sourceGeometry is. It says envelope but do you have an example for that? I read this (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/geometry/Envelope.html) but too many ?s in my head

Comment: Its the geometry you want to convert. It depends on the format you have the GeoJSON data in, but you could use something like the GeometryJSON::read() method. I'll add that to the example.

Comment: I tried but eclipse says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry to org.opengis.geometry.Geometry and suggests to make a typecast to Geometry at jsonreader.read("C:\\Users..."); If I do than there is an error at JTS.transform "The method transform(Envelope, MathTransform) in the type JTS is not applicable for the arguments (Geometry, MathTransform)"

Comment: oh and I did not import anything from vividsolution

Comment: Geometry should be com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry, per the javadoc for JTS class (http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/geometry/jts/JTS.html#transform%28com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry,%20org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform%29). I've updated the example again - I thought that part was obvious, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! Well you could say that I am a beginner. Oh and after I got the following error: "Exception in thread "main" org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No code "EPSG:3068" from authority "EPSG" found for object of type "EngineeringCRS". at ... " I included gt-epsg-hsql-2.7.2.jar in the dependencies but now I get this error: PM org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory createDataSource
INFORMATION: Building new data source for org.geotools.referencing.factory.epsg.ThreadedHsqlEpsgFactory
I am confused -.-

Comment: Perhaps you can generate the CoordinateReferenceSystem using CRS.parseWKT() with the WKT from http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-soldner-berlin/ogcwkt/ . I'll try one more update to the code. If this is too much programming, perhaps you can just use the proj4 command line tools, like cs2cs, instead.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my main post. Could you take a look. And what also confuses me: Why are there 2 MathTransform transforms (one with true and one with false)? And the errors say that there is a connection problem. What could be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, the transform should be "true" - use full scan. http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/CRS.html#lookupIdentifier%28org.opengis.metadata.citation.Citation,%20org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem,%20boolean%29